# CSS 3 make circle bottom shadow full

Tags: css

Hello I have a problem with a circle, I want to create a separation effect. I use box-shadow property: `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);`. As you can see in the picture, the shadow on the left and right is reduced, and the shadow below is full

[image]

Sandbox: https://jsbin.com/wanisewotu/edit?html,css 
How I can make box-shadow full and left and right?

Comment: [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted, or as a stack snippet, when applicable. Do not just dump it onto an external platform, please.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use multiple box-shadow for each side

```
 box-shadow: 12px 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2), -12px 0 0px 0px 
 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

Comment: This not work, I don't need to be shadow top

Comment: box-shadow: 12px 0 0px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -12px 0 0px 0px 
 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

Comment: there is still a shadow on top